# How to keep Tabs selected in ReactJS when I use Material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In this example came from Material-UI, I do not know how to keep tab selected after refresh the web page. There is one the same question which has been asked before. However, that did not be answered. Can someone give me some hints or code example?

```
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="simple tabs example">
          <Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
          <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
          <Tab label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} />
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        Item One
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        Item Two
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
        Item Three
      </TabPanel>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[code exampe](https://codesandbox.io/s/uz2qz)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/am03z.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a different route for each tab and store that information in route.

Route example:-

```
https://uz2qz.csb.app/tabs/1 //tab index 1
https://uz2qz.csb.app/tabs/2 //tab index 2
https://uz2qz.csb.app/tabs/3 //tab index 3
```

**Option 1:-**

On page render fetch the tab index (if any) using `window.location` from the URL and use that information to set the current tab index and pass it to `Tabs` component as a prop.

**Option 2:-**

Using React Router.
Create a route with the path variable using Route component

[React Router example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params)

```
<Switch>
  ...
  <Route path="/tabs/:tabIndex" component={TabsComponent}/>
  ...
</Switch>
```

TabsComponent.js

```
    class TabsComponent extends React.Component {

      render() {
        const { match } = this.props;
        const { params } = match;
        const tabIndex = params.tabIndex ? params.tabIndex : 0;

        return (
          <div className={classes.root}>
            <AppBar position="static">
              <Tabs value={tabIndex} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="simple tabs example">
                <Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
                <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
                <Tab label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} />
              </Tabs>
            </AppBar>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
              Item One
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
              Item Two
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
              Item Three
            </TabPanel>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: For Gods sake, how does this line do any good? `const tabIndex = params.tabIndex ? params.tabIndex : 0;`